# Replace nth appearance of string A in file 1 to nth appearance of string B in file 2 with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Have 2 files, file 1 contains something like:

```
Boa bla bla
Mother name is Charlotte
Kikikiki
Mother name is Bethany
Oooo
Pppp
Wee
Mother name is Rachel
Bla
```

And file 2 looks like:

```
Vijdidkd
Father
Father
Ididj
Father
```

I would need to copy in order all Mother names from file 1 into the lines in file 2 where “Father” appears.

I’ve tried several things, bu I just don’t have enough knowledge I’m sure.

The problem I'm encountering is that from file1 I can extract the info and save it as suggested in one of the answers, however, I can't then pass it onto file2 with the correct order and the correct items onto it.

The files I am trying to get info from are a bit more complex and I maybe tried to simplify too much.

This is the text I've tried and actually replaces the instances in the second file with the text from the first one, but if I have more elements in the first file per instance than in the second one, they start getting mixed up.

The original files look as follows:

```
    <imagenes>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8668.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="1"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8669.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8682.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8683.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8684.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8685.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8681.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8680.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8679.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8674.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8675.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8676.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8677.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8690.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8687.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8691.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8692.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8670.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8671.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534481/image/IMG_8695.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
</imagenes>
<documentos/>
<enlaces>
<enlace idioma="ru">
http://www.nextproperty.es/details-gb534481.html?lan=gb
</enlace>
<enlace idioma="se">
http://www.nextproperty.es/details-gb534481.html?lan=gb
</enlace>
</enlaces>
</propiedad>
<propiedad id="534483">
<fecha_alta>17/10/2018 19:56</fecha_alta>
<fecha_modificacion>07/11/2018 23:32</fecha_modificacion>
<referencia>LM102</referencia>
<familia id="1">Apartamento</familia>
<operacion id="1">Venta</operacion>
<estado id="SM"/>
<dormitorios>3</dormitorios>
<banos>2</banos>
<aseos/>
<localizacion>
<provincia>Murcia</provincia>
<poblacion id="300081">La Manga</poblacion>
<cp>30384</cp>
<zona/>
<pais>ES</pais>
</localizacion>
<superficies>
<habitable/>
<construida>87</construida>
<parcela>110</parcela>
<cocina/>
<salon/>
<jardin>80</jardin>
<terraza/>
</superficies>
<precio divisa="EUR">119500</precio>
<etiquetas>
<etiqueta>Ocasión</etiqueta>
</etiquetas>
<descripciones>
<descripcion idioma="gb">
<titulo>3 bedroom ground floor apartment with large garden</titulo>
<descripcion>
This lovely 3 bedroom ground floor apartment in Mar de Cristal is in a great condition, ready to move into. It has a large terraced garden with entrance for a car, located in a very quiet area, inside a block with a communal pool and safe for children to play around. It features a light and spacious living room, 3 double bedrooms, 2 full bathrooms, a fully equipped kitchen and has central A/C throughout the apartment[IW]
</descripcion>
</descripcion>
</descripciones>
<imagenes>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8695.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="1"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8712.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8717.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8711.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8709.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8710.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8696.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8697.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8698.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8699.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8700.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8701.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8703.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8704.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8705.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8706.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8707.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8708.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8713.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8714.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8715.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
<imagen url="https://storage.googleapis.com/static.inmoweb.es/clients/1652/property/534483/image/IMG_8716.JPG_thumb.jpg" principal="0"/>
</imagenes>
<documentos/>
```

And the file where I wish to output is the following:

```
<property last_updated_at="2014-01-26T20:30:03Z">

    <reference>T800</reference>

    <is_sale>true</is_sale>

    <sale_price hide="false">49000</sale_price>

    <property_type>Apartamento</property_type>

    <bedrooms>2</bedrooms>

    <bathrooms>1</bathrooms>

    <province>Alicante</province>

    <city>Torrevieja</city>

    <latitude />

    <longitude />

    <build_size>55</build_size>

    <plot_size />

    <terrace_size>5</terrace_size>

    <parking_spaces />

    <floor_number />

    <furnished>true</furnished>

    <descriptions>
      <description language="en">
        <text>
Bonito apartamento en Calle Clemente Gonzalvez de dos dormitorios, ba&#241;o, cocina equipada, comedor estar y terraza de 5 m2. A 5 minutos a pie de la plaza del Ayuntamiento.Rodeado de todos los servicios. Ahora en oferta, antes 54.000&#8364; ahora 49.000 &#8364;. Buen estado. Ideal Par vivir todo el a&#241;o o vacaciones.[IW]
</text>
      </description>
    </descriptions>

    <photos>
      <photo id="1" />
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
    </photos>
  </property>



  <property last_updated_at="2014-01-26T20:30:03Z">

    <reference>T702</reference>

    <is_sale>true</is_sale>

    <sale_price hide="false">65000</sale_price>

    <property_type>Apartamento</property_type>

    <bedrooms />

    <bathrooms />

    <province>Alicante</province>

    <city>Torrevieja</city>

    <latitude />

    <longitude />

    <build_size>60</build_size>

    <plot_size />

    <terrace_size />

    <parking_spaces />

    <floor_number />

    <furnished>true</furnished>

    <descriptions>
      <description language="en">
        <text>
Bonito apartamento de 2 dormitorios con piscina comunitaria en Nueva Torrevieja. Cerca de todos los servicios y en perfecto estado.[IW]
</text>
      </description>
    </descriptions>

    <photos>
      <photo id="1" />
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>
<photo></photo>

    </photos>
  </property>
```

What is happening now is that all the  tags from the original file go on the place of  tags from the second file, however, it doesn't take into account that maybe the first group of  tags has 8 elements and I need to leave the last 2 elements of  tags empty, waiting to move to the next group of  tags in order to start pasting again.

This is the code I'm using as of now, and I'm facing this problem.
Sorry for the immensly long question.

```
with open('inmoweb.xml', 'r') as origin :
    data = origin.readlines()
    mothers = ''
    for line in data :
        if '<imagen url' in line :
            mothers += (line)
    mothers += '\n'
    origin.close()

with open('./RESULTS/RESULT_TOTAL.xml', 'r') as f :
    data2 = f.readlines()
    f.close()


yt=0

with open('./RESULTS/RESULT_TOTAL.xml', 'w') as f :
    for line in data2 :
        if '<photo />' in line :
            f.write(mothers.splitlines()[yt])
            f.write('\n')
        else :
            f.write(line)
        if (yt+1) < len(mothers.splitlines()):
            yt+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give a more precise description of your problem?
You want the result like this or something else?

```
Vi
jdidkd
Father   --change to--> mother name1, name2, name3.. 
Father   --change to--> mother name1, name2, name3.. 
Ididj
Father   --change to--> mother name1, name2, name3..
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest way to do this:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    mothers = ''
    for line in data:
        if line.find('Mother name is '):
            line.replace('Mother name is ', '')
            mothers += (line + ', ')
    mothers += '\n'
    f.close()

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    f.close()

with open('file2.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in data:
        if line == 'Father\n':
            f.write(mothers)
        else:
            f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still trying to understand approach and goal on my mobile, here already some thoughts that might help until I can test sth... :

- There's not a single line in file2 which has '' in it.
- With a with-block for opening files you don't need to call close, it's done for you automatically
- You can directly iterate over the file object, no need for `readlines` to do so